# Disposing watchers in a component which is kept alive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have components/pages of a certain type that are kept alive with `<keep-alive>`:

```
<keep-alive :include="['TheComponentName']">
  <component :is="pageComponentName" v-if="currentPage" :key="currentPage.componentKey" /> 
</keep-alive>
```

Works fine. Each of the pages contains sub components with watchers, e.g.

```
<keep-alive>
  <some-page key="theComponentKey">
    <some-component-with-watcher /> <---
  </some-page>
</keep-alive>
```

**some-component-with-watcher:**

```
export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    watch(something, () => {
      doStuff()
    })
  }
})
```

When several pages are kept in memory / kept alive, the underlying component watchers are too. So when navigating to the next page, watchers from the previous page are still alive, for obvious reasons. How can I avoid this? Some ideas:

1. Create the watcher in onActivated, store a reference to the unwatch handle, unwatch in onDeactivaed
2. Dispose the page manually, can this be done?
3. Use `<keep-alive :max="2">`. This didn't seem to have any effect.

What I'm after is persisting the page when a user is going from the kept alive page, to another page, then back to end up where they were, so they don't need to be kept alive forever.

Comment: First solution makes the most sense to me. The same should be done with DOM listeners on unmount when properly handled etc. The only thing is that these watchers must be inside onActivated immediate to reflect actual value.